# prevent UIWebView inputs from displaying UIKeyboard without disabling user interaction

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that loads and external product configuration web service UI that is basically a bunch of dependent Drop Down lists.

The problem is the Drop Downs are basically enhanced text input's so when the user taps them to display the options the UIKeyboard keeps popping up and own after they make their selection.  it is less than a fluid process.  Is there anyway to suppress the html inputs from triggering the UIKeyboard?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier not to use <input type="text"> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then try this:

```
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeKeyBoard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
...

- (void)removeKeyBoard:(NSNotification *)notify {
    // web is your UIWebView
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur()"];
}
```

remember to remove the notification and can filter it if only for your WebView object.

Comment: Just saw this answer and if I implement this then the keyboard pops up and goes away again right away - Is there a way I can paste a textField in a textField with the Keyboard popping up at all? Like in the stock Note app? This would have to work on a textfield in a UIWebView though. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code in the HTML:

```
<input type='text' width='100' onclick='blur()'>
```

with the method blur () and then you lose the focus will not appear on the keyboard.

Comment: I do not have control over the HTML